# Sql syntax error using UPDATE database query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

evening all, i have an issue with a syntax sql error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where username = danny (name, url, banner, description, sponsor, date, password)' at line 1
```

Here is my code

```
$query = "UPDATE websites where username = $login_session (name, url, banner, description, sponsor, date, password) VALUES ('$n', '$b', '$d', '0', now(), SHA('$p'))";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `UPDATE` statement syntax is wrong. Check [MySQL documentation for proper UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). I think you meant to do a `INSERT` rather

```
INSERT INTO websites (name, url, banner, description, sponsor, date, password) 
VALUES ('$login_session', '$n', '$b', '$d', '0', now(), SHA('$p'))
```

**EDIT:**

I think this is what you are after

```
UPDATE websites SET name = '$n', 
url = '$b', 
banner = '$d', 
description = '0', 
sponsor = 'some_value_here', 
date = now(), 
password = SHA('$p')
where username = '$login_session';
```

Comment: But this isn't doing any checks, example: i want to update the table that has the username signed in. username = $login_session

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

using:

$query = "INSERT INTO websites (username, name, url, banner, description, sponsor, date, password) 
VALUES ('$login_session', '$n', '$b', '$d', '0', now(), SHA('$p'))";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Check update in answer. You want an UPDATE statement but your syntax is wrong.

Comment: using your new EDIT: gives me this again,  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' date = now(), password = SHA('') where username = danny' at line 5

Comment: Unknown column 'danny' in 'where clause'

Comment: im using: $query = "UPDATE websites SET name = '$n', 
url = '$u', 
banner = '$b', 
description = '$d', 
sponsor = '0', 
date = now(), 
password = SHA('$p')
where username = $login_session;";

returns this:Unknown column 'danny' in 'where clause'

Comment: Have you checked the edit properly, it should be `where username = '$login_session'`. Come on....

Comment: Hey, how would i go about showing what they already have in the database? and they update it ?  my whole page code: http://pastebin.com/xEiXnbcq

Answer (score 3):

Your MySQL query is wrong, as the error says, check the manual.

In `UPDATE` you don't use `table(field,field1) values('value','value1')` like in `INSERT`, you use `field='value', field1='value1'` also, `WHERE` should be at the end, the right order is query + where + order + limit. MySQL is not that flexible.